# Drag & Drop a New Version

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, versioning, drag-and-drop

When a file is drag and dropped into a document library that has versioning enabled (a document set in my case) and a file with that name already exists, SharePoint shows this message:

[image: SP Error]

But when a file is uploaded via the Ribbon > New Document method, it uploads a version.

**Is there a way to drag and drop a versioned file, rather than only having the option to replace the existing file or not upload at all?**

Answer (score 3):

'Replace it' will create a new version of the file if the library has versioning enabled. You can check if the old version was retained by looking at the file's Version History.